# Windows XP/Vista cool tricks for web developer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, notepad

What are some possible tricks you can do with a fresh install Windows XP or Vista that a Web Developer might use. list some of your favorites.

I was looking to turning an ordinary notepad into a code editor with "syntax highlighting", "code formatting" feature. I dunno if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

> What are some possible tricks you can do with a fresh install Windows XP or Vista that a Web Developer might use.

Use Internet Explorer to download Dreamweaver.